# SQL join even there is no such id

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have following query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (
       SELECT 
       catalog.*,
       images.image 
       FROM `catalog` as catalog 
       INNER JOIN `type5` as images ON catalog.id = images.id 
       WHERE catalog.left_key > (SELECT `left_key` FROM `catalog` WHERE `id`=235) AND catalog.right_key < (SELECT `right_key` FROM `catalog` WHERE `id`=235)
       ORDER BY catalog.left_key ASC
   ) ilv
```

This query works well, but it SELECTS only items FROM catalog only if in table type5 is same item id.

For example in in catalog I have:

```
id name
 5 Hello
 7 World
 8 Foo
 9 Bar
```

And in type 5 I have:
id image

```
 5 hello.png
 8 foo.png
 9 bar.png
```

It will selects only

```
 5 Hello
 8 Foo
 9 Bar
```

How to edit my query to select items from catalog even if there is no same id in type5?

Comment: What you need is an outer join. See the wikipedia page on `join (sql)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using an `inner join`, which means it will only get the items which are in both tables.

You're probably looking for a `left outer join`.

If you don't really get how joins work, [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) is a good visual representation which explains it.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT catalog.*, images.image 
FROM `catalog` as catalog 
LEFT JOIN `type5` as images 
     ON catalog.id = images.id 
WHERE 
  catalog.left_key > 
    (SELECT `left_key` FROM `catalog` WHERE `id`=235) 
  AND catalog.right_key < 
    (SELECT `right_key` FROM `catalog` WHERE `id`=235)
ORDER BY catalog.left_key ASC
```

I have no idea what the where clause is trying to do...  but to get all records from catalog and those from image with a related record in catalog, LEFT join is what you need.  I also don't understand what the outer select is for...

Comment: I don't understand that outer select either :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
   SELECT 
   catalog.*,
   images.image 
   FROM `catalog` as catalog 
   ***LEFT OUTER*** JOIN `type5` as images ON catalog.id = images.id 
   WHERE catalog.left_key > (SELECT `left_key` FROM `catalog` WHERE `id`=235) 
   AND catalog.right_key < (SELECT `right_key` FROM `catalog` WHERE `id`=235)
   ORDER BY catalog.left_key ASC
) ilv
```

This query will select all records from your catalog table joined with type5 table. If there is no same id in type5 table NULL values will be selected for such pair.

```
Hello - hello.png
World - NULL
```

The key words are **LEFT** and **OUTER**. If you need replacement for absent values in catalog table you can use **RIGHT OUTER JOIN**. 
To make this all work at the same time - **FULL OUTER JOIN**